# Html ASCII rendering issue

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml, ascii

I'm using Java Resource Bundles to manage messages.

I need to display a message in a web page and the message also contains some HTML markup. Unfortunately the HTML code is also displayed on screen instead of been rendered as HTML by the browser:

```
daggerMessage=‡ &#135; Symbol indicates situational entry, at least one is required.

<p class="text-right asteriskMessage">‡#{heading.daggerMessage}</p>
```

This is what I get.

```
ï¿½ &#135; Symbol indicates situational entry, at least one is required.
```

Any Ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The notation `&#135;` is specific to HTML and XML-based markup languages and should not be expected to work in any context. Moreover, it is formally undefined in HTML prior to HTML5, though in practice web browsers treat it as denoting “‡” U+2021 DOUBLE DAGGER.

The [character “‡”](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2021/index.htm) is 0xE2 0x80 0xA1 in the UTF-8 encoding. It seems that some incorrect mapping is performed on these bytes and then the resulting bytes are interpreted in some 8-bit encoding to yield “ï¿½”. So what you have is encoding mismatch and possibly wrong recoding at that. From the data given, it is impossible to give a more accurate analysis (well, someone might make an intelligent guess...).

Comment: Yes. So the answer is a) to check what kind of encoding is set in the source or in the http header, and b) to use either `&#x2021;` or `&Dagger;` for the dagger.

Comment: @MrLister, a) it’s really a matter of making the actual encoding and declated encoding match, so you need to know both, and b) using `&#x2021;` or `&Dagger;` is unnecessary after you have fixed the a) issue.

Comment: It might be unnecessary, but it's better than `&#135;` which is always an error. And solving a) might not even be that easy if you don't know where to look.